# How to get this attribute value in XML using DOM

Tags: php, xml

Assuming i have an XML document as such,

```
<node id="234" label="somewhere" >
    <attvalues>
        <attvalue for="ware" value="ews"/>
        <attvalue for="soft" value="sed"/>
        <attvalue for="time" value="121"/>
        <attvalue for="life" value="mone"/>  
    </attvalues>
</node>
```

How may i get only the value for "time" element which is 121 ?

This is what i do to get the attibutes of node :

```
foreach($node->getElementsByTagName('attvalue') as $value){

            $enA[] = $value->getAttribute('for');
            $evA[] = $value->getAttribute('value');

}
```

But what if i want only time attribute value ? because the code above gives all attributes and their values. I don't know how to be more specific.

I tried something like

```
 $evA[] = $value->getAttribute('time');
```

But doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($node->getElementsByTagName('attvalue') as $value) {
    if ($value->getAttribute('for') != 'time') {
        continue;
    }

    $timeValue = $value->getAttribute('value');
    break;
}
```

If XML might have more than one time attvalue, define `$timeValue` as an array and then add values using `$timeValue[]` or `array_push()` function like this:

```
    $timeValue[] = $value->getAttribute('value');
    // break; also do not forget to remove the break operator.
```

You can also query that value with XPath directly:

```
$xp = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$value = $xp->evaluate('/node/attvalues/attvalue[@for="time"]/@value');
```